# Displaying a table (dataframe) with ggtexttable

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I want to output a table with `ggtexttable`. A screen shot of the table looks like this:

[image]

If I display the table with

```
ggtexttable(Data_round, rows = NULL)
```

it looks like this:

[image]

Which settings/parameters do I have to use to display the whole table?

Comment: Please do not post an image of data [for these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Just include the data directly using e.g. `dput()`, i.e. run `dput(head(Data_round))` and copy & paste the output into your post.

Comment: The whole table _is_ displayed, but it is a fixed size, so you need to make your plotting device larger to see more of it.  The easiest, and most aesthetic way, to improve this would be simply to shorten your column names to something legible, understandable and small enough to fit comfortably in the available space. The reason your table does not fit completely into your plotting window is that your column names are simply too long to fit unless you shrink the text down, but then it will be barely legible.

Comment: Hallo Allan, your Solution works for me. But if we can not reduce the length of the column name, what can we do?